# I have no clue when to write 'if line.startswith('From: ')' and 'if not line.startswith('From')

Tags: python

Following is the question from some assignment:

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.

This is one of the code (found online) that works for this question. Could someone explain when do i have to write 'if line.startswith()' and/or 'if not line.startswith()' and if at all we can use both of these codes consecutively line after other?

```
fname = input("Enter file:")
if len(fname) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
hand = open(fname)

lst = list()

for line in hand:
    if not line.startswith("From:"): continue
    line = line.split()
    lst.append(line[1])

counts = dict()
for word in lst:
    counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1

bigcount = None
bigword = None
for word,count in counts.items(): 
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigcount = count
        bigword = word

print (bigword,bigcount)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Explain this code to me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.  In essence, you're asking for a personal tutorial in Boolean logic and string processing.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use `if line.startswith('FROM')` because it reads better and makes more sense for the purpose of the task.

You could use both `line.startswith()` and `not line.startswith()` if you wanted to perform different actions depending on starting characters of the line, but in your situation you should be using one of those.

Also I might point out that this is not very Pythonic:

```
if len(fname) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
```

...particularly the `len(fname) < 1`. Instead we should use the fact that an empty string is "falsy" in Python and simply write:  `if not fname:`. Once again, this reads much better.

Finally, you shouldn't normally open files directly like so:

```
hand = open(fname)
```

Because you might forget to close it afterwards (which you did). You should use `with` statement instead [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).